# Required a bean of type 'jakarta.persistence.EntityManager' that could not be found

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa

I'm trying to compile my Spring Boot project, but I'm having trouble running the application due to the error **required a bean of type 'jakarta.persistence.EntityManager' that could not be found.** the error is in **TypeHunterDAOJpaImplementation.java**.

- `application.properties`

```
# PostgreSQL
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/my_database
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=12345678
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
```

- `TypeHunter.java`

```
import jakarta.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name="type_hunters")
public class TypeHunter {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue (strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name="description")
    private String description;

    public TypeHunter() {  // No-arg constructor for JPA

    }

    public TypeHunter(int id, String description) {
        this.id = id;
        this.description = description;
    }

    public int getId() { return id; }
    public void setId(int id) { this.id = id; }
    public String getDescription() { return description; }
    public void setDescription(String description) { this.description = description; }
}
```

- `TypeHunterDAO.java`

```
import java.util.List;

public interface TypeHunterDAO {

    List<TypeHunter> findAll();

}
```

- `TypeHunterDAOJpaImplementation.java`

```
import jakarta.persistence.EntityManager;
import jakarta.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import jakarta.persistence.TypedQuery;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import java.util.List;

@Repository
public class TypeHunterDAOJpaImplementation implements TypeHunterDAO {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Autowired
    public TypeHunterDAOJpaImplementation(EntityManager theEntityManager){
        entityManager = theEntityManager;
    }

    @Override
    public List<TypeHunter> findAll() {
        if (entityManager == null) throw new IllegalStateException("EntityManager does not work correctly.");
        TypedQuery<TypeHunter> query = entityManager.createQuery("from TypeHunter", TypeHunter.class);
        return query.getResultList();
    }

}
```

- `TypeHunterREST.java`

```
import com.user.springboot3.project.DAO.TypeHunterDAO;
import com.user.springboot3.project.Entity.TypeHunterHunter;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import java.util.List;

@RequestMapping("/api")
@RestController
public class TypeHunterRest {

    private TypeHunterDAO type_hunter;

    public TypeHhnterRest(TypeHunterDAO typeHunterDAO) {
        this.type_hunter = typeHunterDAO;
    }

    @GetMapping("/type-hunter")
    public List<TypeHunter> findAll() {
        return type_hunter.findAll();
    }
}
```

The action recommended is **Consider defining a bean of type 'jakarta.persistence.EntityManager' in your configuration.**

In my `pom.xml` has:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.6.6.Final</version>
        </dependency>
```

It would must be working, i guess.

Comment: Remove the `hibernate-entitymanager`, remove the `jakarta.persistence-api` dependency. I assume you already have the `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` as a dependency if you don't add it. Restart your application. And no only adding `spring-data-jpa` isn't enough, if you have that remove that as well. The `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` includes **all needed dependencies** like `spring-data-jpa`, `hibernate` etc. in compatible versions.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use only one way to make injection of EntityManager.

Use:

```
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager entityManager;
```

or :

```
@Autowired
private EntityManager em;
```

Or :

```
@Autowired
public TypeHunterDAOJpaImplementation(EntityManager theEntityManager){
    entityManager = theEntityManager;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
   <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

  </dependencies>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).